# Zabbix - Trigger an email if a certain string is present in website

Tags: regex, monitoring, zabbix

I've started to use Zabbix (version 4.0) some weeks ago with the intent of constantly monitoring my company's websites and applications. I easily made it monitor the response code and download time for some sits, and even check if some crucial strings are present on it. That means, in the steps of my web scenario, I've configured Zabbix to search for a string on the website and trigger an error email **if the string isn't present.**

What I have to do now, though, is the exact opposite: **I have to configure Zabbix to trigger a string *is* present on the website.**

For example: I have the website www.myprettyexample.com, monitored by Zabbix. If there's the string "*Error detected!!*" present in its HTML, Zabbix will trigger me an e-mail, warning about it somehow.

So, is this possible to accomplish? How? And if not, what could be the best workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the new [http agent check](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/http).

Configure an item of http agent type on your Zabbix server with these settings:

- key: choose a key name
- url: www.myprettyexample.com/somepage.html
- method: get
- retrieve mode: body
- type: text

This will capture the whole page and store it (keep the storage checked!), you can check the capture in the "Latest Data" page.

Then you can create a simple regexp trigger like `{YourZabbix:YourKey.iregexp("Error detected")}=1`.

While it works, it could be a waste of your storage: a better approach is to capture a json status page (if exists) of a specific status page with a small footprint.

Comment: As far as I testes here, that is, indeed, the answer! However, in my specific case, I need to read an element added in the HTML body by JavaScript... And Zabbix doesn't seem able to find it. When I read the HTML code, all elements are present, but the one I added via script at the bottom of the body (probably the script haven't finished executing by the time Zabbix read the HTML). Would you know some way to solve this?

Comment: Zabbix uses libCurl, so it can't run javascript. You need an external tool which runs js code. I've found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/domcurl, but I never tried it. Of course, you'll need to setup a different item, a system.run[] or an external script